# Access the catalina.out files inside docker container

Tags: docker

I can see a tomcat container after running the command `docker ps` command via Power Shell on my windows. I'm wondering how can I access the file as `docker ps` command just lists the `container ID`, `Image` , `command`, `created`, `status`, `ports` and `names`. And on the Docker desktop, if I click on the tomcat9, I can see Logs, Inspect, Terminal, Files and Stats but on the Terminal, I could onlly see that catalina.out is inside the logs folder as shown in thei mage below:

[image]

But I can't access the contents of the file using vi editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `vi` is not installed in the container.

However, you can view the contents of the logs in a variety of ways (see screenshot). Use `head` to see the first few lines of a file. Similarly, use `tail` to see the last few lines. You can dump the entire contents of the file to the terminal using `cat`. But that's probably not very user-friendly. Rather use `more` to get a paginated view of the logs.

[image]

If you really want to run `vim` then just install it onto the running container.

```bash
apt-get update
apt-get install vim
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you also share the commands for `cat` and `more` as well in case I want to use both options?

Comment: Sure thing. The syntax is essentially the same, just replace `head` with `cat` or `more`. The general form for these commands is `cat <filename>` and `more <filename>`.

Comment: Thanks. Is this command going to work for live logs `tail -f catalina.out` I remember using it on RHEL server (not on docker) and it used to show me live logs. Also, is it something easy to handle or see using Windows Power Shell?

Comment: Yes, that will give you a constantly updated view of the end of the log file. This command will be running inside the container, so it's effectively running in a Linux environment (which is what you have in the Docker Desktop terminal for the container).

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if I can download this complete file from some location in case I don't want to go with commands?

Comment: And where in container I need to go to install `vim` ?

Comment: Just install it directly into the terminal session. Run the two commands provided in my answer.

Comment: OK. I am wondering, if `vi` is going to stay next time tomcat container is running. I mean every time I start my app, it starts showing the tomcat9 on the Docker and hence I was wondering if I install the `vi` using the commands, is the installation going to stay there the next time my tomcat9 instance runs? Thanks!

Comment: If you start a new container then you'll have to install again. If you want vi to always be installed then you should create a simple derived Docker image which installs it.